# Why do some rows in csv file have an invalid format?

Tags: python, csv

I am currently fetching data from an API and I would like to store those data as csv.

However, some lines are always invalid which means I cannot split them via Excel's text-in-columns functionality.

I create the csv file as follows:

```
with open(directory_path + '/' + file_name + '-data.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
    # Setup a writer
    csvwriter = csv.writer(file, delimiter='|')

    # Write headline row
    if not headline_exists:
        csvwriter.writerow(['Title', 'Text', 'Tip'])

    # Build the data row
    record = data['title'] + '|' + data['text'] + '|' + data['tip']

    csvwriter.writerow([record])
```

[image: invalid csv]

If you open the csv file in Excel you also immediately see that the row is invalid. While the valid one takes the default height and the whole width, the invalid one takes more height but less width.

Does anyone know a reason for that problem?

Comment: It looks like you aren't telling excel to use pipes `|` as the delimiter. It's probably trying to use something else and breaking things. Additionally, you aren't leveraging csvwriter at all - you're manually building rows and writing them as plain strings. `csv` will let you give it a dictionary mapping and a dictionary/list of dictionaries and write based on keys. Look into `csv.DictWriter` if this is getting much bigger.

Comment: `record = data['title'] + '|' + data['text'] + '|' + data['tip']` is 1 column not 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found out that I had to strip the text and the tip because they sometimes contain whitespaces which would break the format.

Additionally, I also followed the recommendation to use the `excel dialect` since I think this will make it easier to process the data later on.

Answer (score 1):

The rows are not invalid, but what you do is.

So first of all: You use pipes as delimeters. Its fine in some scenarios, but given the fact you want to load it into excel immediately it seems wiser to me to export the data in ["excel" dialect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
csvwriter = csv.writer(file, dialect='excel')
```

Second, look at the following lines:

```
record = data['title'] + '|' + data['text'] + '|' + data['tip']
csvwriter.writerow([record])
```

This way you basically tell the csv writer that you want a single column, with pipes in it. If you use a csv writer you must not concatenate the delimeters on your own, it voids the point of using a writer. So this is how it should be done instead:

```
record = [data['title'], data['text'], data['tip']]
csvwriter.writerow(record)
```

Hope it helps.